# Attaching curtain rail to plasterboard/drywall over studwork

Tags: drywall, curtain-rail

[image]We've had some new uPVC windows fitted. The upstairs bay window presented some problems and, as a result, the "wall" above the window frame is now studwork with cement board on the external side and plasterboard on the internal side.

Before the work, the curtain rail (a cheap plastic one) was attached to what appeared to be a wooden section above the old window frame.

We're going to purchase a new curtain rail but I'm confused about whether I should be thinking about attaching the curtain rail brackets directly to the plasterboard or (as I've had suggested to me) attach some wooden batten to the plasterboard and then attach the curtain rail brackets to that.

I'm pretty naive when it comes to home improvements so if my question is unclear let me know and I'll edit for clarity.

I'm in the UK if that changes anything. The house itself was built in 1885 and is of brick and bungaroosh construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you attach the curtain hardware into the stud framing around the window, the only reason to add any extra wood to mount the brackets is if you need to move the bracket out from the wall to get clear of any window trim, or if the hardware must be installed somewhere that doesn't have any studs behind it and you use the wood piece to span the space between the studs.

You can set the hardware directly on the plaster, or some installs may have it on the trim surrounding the window, but either way, you want a long screw that can reach and hold into the stud to avoid the curtains pulling out the old hardware.

Comment: So attaching the curtain hardware to plasterboard that doesn't have any stud behind it (e.g. using plasterboard fixings or toggle bolts) is a bad idea? I believe the studwork is wood, so it should be relatively straight forward to attach into that.
Thanks!

Comment: Correct, this hardware has a lot of stress on it, and needs to be anchored into the solid wood framing behind the plaster. The plaster will blow out if you only use a toggle bolt, see some of the other questions from people that have accidentally pulled out their curtains for the ways it's been done wrong before.